# How do I properly link this gdi+ example to a library file?

Tags: c++, linker, gdi+

I copied an example from Microsoft to display a line using GDI+ but I got some errors that have to do with the linker not being set up right for 'gdiplus.lib'. I got these errors:

-relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `GdipDrawLineI'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
-undefined reference to`GdiplusStartup'

How do I set up this program to work right?

I tried putting the folder that contained gdiplus.lib by right clicking the project (using netbeans) and clicking properties>linker>additional library directories>"C:\…\". I also tried putting gdiplus.lib in 'additional dependencies' in the same window.

I know java very well and am just starting out with c++ and really just need a graphics example to study before porting my programs.

Comment: microsoft's example code can be found at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/walkthrough-creating-windows-desktop-applications-cpp?view=vs-2019#feedback

Comment: Which compiler do you use?

Comment: I use NetBeans.

Answer (score 1):

Netbeans uses gcc and and MinGW. You need *.a files instead of Windows *.lib files.

If MinGW/w64 is installed correctly, look for `"libgdiplus.a"` in your MinGW directory:

`"c:\MinGW\lib\libgdiplus.a"` (mingw could be in  a different path)

You can also use `-lgdiplus` compiler flag.

```
g++ -Wall file.cpp -mwindows -lgdi32 -lgdiplus -o app.exe
```

Comment: I copied and pasted the "draw a line" for GDI+ example from Microsoft at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/gdiplus/-gdiplus-drawing-a-line-use into a new project main file. I highlighted out the first line of code: #include <stdafx.h>, because I was told it was unnecessary and it was giving me recurrent header requirement errors. I put "c:\MinGW\lib\libgdiplus.a" in additional dependencies of the linker window. I cleaned and built the copied file and got 2 errors plus several 'undefined references'.

Comment: Yes, remove `stdafx.h` which is Visual Studio specific. I don't know what other errors you are getting. You have to edit your question or start a new question. Are you able to make a plain Windows program without GDI+?